# Is there an idiomatic way to do "in" for golang slices

Tags: go, idioms

I would like to check if a value is in a slice of values. What is the best way to achieve this?
Something like the following:

```
if "foo" in []string{"foo", "bar"}...
```

I've written the following code but not sure how idiomatic it is (golang newbie):

```
// Convert a slice or array of a specific type to array of interface{}
func ToIntf(s interface{}) []interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    // There is no need to check, we want to panic if it's not slice or array
    intf := make([]interface{}, v.Len())
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        intf[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
    }
    return intf
}
func In(s []interface{}, val interface{}) bool {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == val {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

So, to use this, here is a test method I wrote.

```
func TestIn(t *testing.T) {
    s := []string{"foo", "bar", "kuku", "kiki"}
    for _, v := range s {
        if !In(ToIntf(s), v) {
            t.Error("Should be in")
        }
    }
    if In(ToIntf(s), "foobar") {
        t.Error("Should not be in")
    }
}
```

Comment: From a performance standpoint I don't like it because it is adding a bunch of work through interface{} pointers that is pointless, aside from not having to write one copy of `In()` for each data type.

Answer (score 8):

The idiomatic way, in go, for functions that can be expressed with a simple loop, to be implemented that way. Your method, for example, could be written that way:

```
for _, value := range slice {
    if value == var {
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

Obviously, it is somewhat more verbose, but that only if you try to *translate* `language or choice here` in go.

The downside of doing reflection is that you botch performances without being that simpler than if you write your code to integrate to the search rather than simply considering it a condition.

Comment: Of course I agree regarding performance but not all code has to be "the most efficient" and if I know that the slice size will be very small I would prefer not to be that verbose.

Comment: PS - I just ran a short test on my laptop and for 10,000,000 slice of strings it takes less than a second. Now, consider the use case of me trying to check if a value is not in a list of values. Now, your code suddenly becomes:

`in := false
for _, value := range slice {
    if value == var {
        in = true
        break
    }
}
if !in {
    doSomething()
}`

Instead of: if !In(slice, val) {doSomething()}

Answer (score 0):

if you need a cheap way to check this (if you have to check it often) i would use a map for cheaper lookups. like this:

```
type Foo string

var sl []string
var m map[string]int

//insert
sl = append(sl, "bar")
m["bar"] += 1

// delete ,e.g at position i
m[sl[i]] -= 1
sl[len(sl)-1], s[:len(sl)-1]


//test
if count := m["abc"]; count>0 {
 // "abc" in sl 
}
```

Of course both will add overhead if you change something in the slice. That would depend on your case.

If your slice does not change, and you will do a lot of "in" testing you could build an easier map for that:

```
m := make(map[string]struct{}, len(sl))
for _, value := range sl {
    m[value] = struct{}
}

//test 

if _, ok := m["abc"]; ok {
  // "abc" is in sl
}
```